# SwiftUI pin partial list to bottom

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios14

I've got a list of chat messages that scrolls up as new messages are added at the end. But if there are too few messages in the view, they pin at the top.

Is there a way to pin the contents at the bottom?

Note that in this case, the view is inside a `UIHostingController`.

```swift
struct OverlayChatView: View {
    @ObservedObject public  var stream: ChatStream
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { scrollView in
            ScrollView {
                LazyVStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0.0) {
                    ForEach(self.stream.messages) { inMsg in
                        ChatMessageCell(message: inMsg)
                    }
                    .padding(8)
                }
            }
            .onAppear {
                if self.stream.messages.count > 0
                {
                    scrollView.scrollTo(self.stream.messages.last!.id, anchor: .bottom)
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: self.stream.messages, perform: { inMessages in
                if inMessages.count < 1 { return }
                
                withAnimation(.linear(duration: 0.25)) {
                    scrollView.scrollTo(inMessages.last!.id, anchor: .bottom)
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated the post to show the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m not thoroughly satisfied with this answer, as it requires some hard-coding and isn’t as elegant as direct support within the `ScrollView` to just allow scrolling past the end of content, but it’s fairly simple.

@jnpdx was on the right track with his answer above.

In the weeks since I posted this question, I’ve learned many more SwiftUI techniques. In this case, you can add almost arbitrary padding and views inside a `ScrollView`, both inside and outside the contained list/stack/whatever (but not inside the `ForEach`, that won’t do what you want!).

I wrapped the `ScrollViewReader` in a `GeometryReader` in order to make the overall chat view height available to the views inside, and then I added padding atop the `LazyVStack` equal to the height minus a hard-coded amount equal to the height of one line of chat (this is the hard-coded part I don’t like).

```swift
struct OverlayChatView: View {
    @ObservedObject public  var stream: ChatStream
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader
        { inChatView in
            ScrollViewReader { scrollView in
                ScrollView {
                    LazyVStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0.0) {
                        ForEach(self.stream.messages) { inMsg in
                            ChatMessageCell(message: inMsg)
                        }
                        .padding(.top, inChatView.size.height - 26.0)
                        .padding([.horizontal, .bottom], 8)
                    }
                }
                .onAppear {
                    if self.stream.messages.count > 0
                    {
                        scrollView.scrollTo(self.stream.messages.last!.id, anchor: .bottom)
                    }
                }
                .onChange(of: self.stream.messages, perform: { inMessages in
                    if inMessages.count < 1 { return }
                
                    withAnimation(.linear(duration: 0.25)) {
                        scrollView.scrollTo(inMessages.last!.id, anchor: .bottom)
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This provides the additional content the `ScrollView` needs to let you scroll all the way down.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a dynamically-sized `Spacer` based on the difference between the height of the content and the height of the entire scroll view. If the content is smaller, display a `Spacer` -- if not, just display the content.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var contentHeight : CGFloat = 0
    @State private var totalHeight : CGFloat = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { scroller in
            ScrollView {
                if contentHeight < totalHeight {
                    Spacer().frame(height: totalHeight - contentHeight)
                }
                VStack {
                    Text("My content")
                    Text("More content")
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(GeometryReader {
                    Color.clear.preference(key: ContentHeight.self,
                                           value: $0.frame(in: .local).size.height)
                })
                .onPreferenceChange(ContentHeight.self) { contentHeight = $0 }
            }
            .background(GeometryReader {
                Color.clear.preference(key: TotalHeight.self,
                                       value: $0.frame(in: .local).size.height)
            })
            .border(Color.red)
            .onPreferenceChange(TotalHeight.self) { totalHeight = $0 }
        }
    }
    
    struct TotalHeight : PreferenceKey {
        static var defaultValue: CGFloat { 0 }
        static func reduce(value: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) {
            value = value + nextValue()
        }
    }

    struct ContentHeight : PreferenceKey {
        static var defaultValue: CGFloat { 0 }
        static func reduce(value: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) {
            value = value + nextValue()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Comment: Haven't had a chance to try it yet, but I will try it! I think I'm going to file a bug requesting built-in support for this though, as that's quite a lot of work!

Comment: Okay. An upvote is always good if the answer is helpful at all.